# Can't boot from HDD on HP NC8000, but booting from HDD via HirensBootCD works ok

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, mbr

I've moved my old 160 GB Samsung harddrive from my old notebook Compaq EVO N1020V to HP NC8000. Now it do not boots. It's mounted in internal bay and BIOS is set to boot from hardrive first.

I've got only blinking cursor on black screen.

I was guessing that boot sector is different. I've tried booting from installation disc and:

- fixboot
- fixmbr
- OS reinstallation in repair mode

nothing helps.

The only way I can boot is to boot computer from HirensBootCD and then select fix NTDLR and first option. Then it boots right away into Windows.

How to correct this problem ?

Comment: Have you tested the health of the Hard Drive?

Comment: Yes, it ok. It's just about half a year old and about 1000 Power On Hours. SMART ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to install Windows 7 on second partition which installed new Windows 7 bootloader on drive C. Then again start from Windows 7 DVD click Repair This Computer, then bcdedit /delete {current} and voila. System is booting in Windows XP directly from disk :) Then I've formatted partition D, merged partition C and D and all is working fine with single partition.

Answer (score 0):

The new laptop probably has a different SATA controller and the drivers on the hard drive wont work.

Comment: This laptop is not using SATA at all...